# Show custom data instead of 404

Tags: plugin-development, redirect, 404-error

I'm currently developing a plugin to display some custom data on my wordpress site.

For example I have a data named `abc`. If a visitor try to access `localhost/wordpress/abc`, it should display the data programatically from code. But if a valid post url is accessed like `localhost/wordpress/existing-post` it should still display the post.

I've currently looking into trapping 404 redirect using `template_redirect` action and `redirect_canonical` filter, but the solution doesn't feel right. Also I'm looking into using custom post type but not sure whether it's suitable.

I've tried by create a post for each data, and use `the_content` filter to display the detail of the data, but this method generate too many posts so I'm looking for a cleaner alternative.

The data I have is generated in the background over time. So it will grow to thousands or tens of thousands in the future.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I've adopted `404 Tools plugin` by toscho. These is the essential part that I've modified and use

```
add_filter( '404_template', 'myplugin_display_data' );
public function myplugin_display_data( $template )
{
    status_header(200);
    new self;
    //For now forward everything to my own page for testing purpose
    return dirname(__FILE__) . '/myplugin-page.php';
}
```

Now I notice that the output will have `error404` in part of the CSS class of the body, which still render the output like 404. How should I make it like a `post` or `page` without manually overriding variables `$wp_query`, e.g. doing `$wp_query->is_page = true;`

I'm looking for an elegant way to do this.

EDIT:
I've added

```
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->parse_query("/");
```

After `status_header`, and now the page is displayed the way I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: What does 'data' mean? Where is it stored? Is it code or content?

Comment: Why do you need a plugin for that? Isn't editing 404.php easier?

Comment: 'Data' is content generated based on data is stored in the db. When the redirection reaches 404.php, the header of 404 is already sent. I wanted the "page" to appear as ordinary page which existed.

Comment: so this doesn't really have anything to do with the 404 page.  You just want a url where the data is displayed? The data is not a WP post but something stored in its own non-wordpress-specific db tables? If so you could make a Page named 'abc' and a page template named 'page-abc.php', and in the page template do all work needed to query the data tables and display the data.

Comment: @Natebot You're right, it's actually has nothing to do with 404. But the string 'abc' is unique to each data, that's why I didn't want to resort to creating page/post for each data. 'abc' is actually the query string or name of the data, so I can retrieve it from the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at my [404 Tools plugin](https://github.com/toscho/T5-404-Tools). I run a filter on `'404_template'` there. The filter function is getting the template URL as an argument, and it is still possible to send HTTP headers.

You could hook into this filter too, prepare some data you may need to print out later, change the template (eg.: to `single.php`) and add a `do_action( 'print_my_custom_data' );` to your `single.php`.

Comment: It's close, but I would prefer to intercept even before WP decided this is 404. Which filters comes before `404_template`?

Comment: @faulty A lot! :) Try my plugin [Plugin All Actions List](https://gist.github.com/1979171) to find a better one.